Geodesic curve, why dervative of length functional variation is in tangent space?
I was looking at this pdf. In page3,

Don't understand why that underlined statment is correct. Although the pdf has a picture 
I was thinking to show $\langle \frac{d}{d\lambda}|_0~\alpha_\lambda (s), N_{\alpha(s)} \rangle = 0$
This also $= \frac{d}{d\lambda}|_0 \langle\alpha_\lambda (s), N_{\alpha(s)} \rangle - \langle\alpha_\lambda (s), \frac{d}{d\lambda}|_0  N_{\alpha(s)} \rangle
=\frac{d}{d\lambda}|_0 \langle\alpha_\lambda (s), N_{\alpha(s)} \rangle - 0$
But this may not be $0$ generally.

Just when I'm writing the question explicitly, suddenly understand!
Use definition of derivative, consider fixed $s$ and varying $\lambda$, then
$\frac{d}{d\lambda}|_0~\alpha_\lambda (s) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\alpha_h(s)-\alpha_0(s)}{h}$
We know $\alpha_\lambda$ is some curve on surface for fixed $\lambda$, then $\alpha_h(s)$ and $\alpha_0(s)$ are just some points on the surface. As $h\to0$, $\alpha_h(s) \to \alpha_0(s)$
Lets consider the smooth curve generated by varying $\lambda$ for this $s$ , it passes  through two points mentioned above, the $\lim$ is just definition of $\lambda$-derivative of a smooth curve, at the point $\alpha_0(s)$. By definition, it is in the tangent space.

That's the great thing about trying to express your confusion so well that others can comprehend it --- it often clears things up for you. (See "Rubber ducky debugging".)
